# Multiply Large Complex Number Vector by Scalar efficiently C++

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, sse, simd, complex-numbers

I'm currently trying to most efficiently do an in-place multiplication of an array of complex numbers (memory aligned the same way the std::complex would be but currently using our own ADT) by an array of scalar values that is the same size as the complex number array.

The algorithm is already parallelized, i.e. the calling object splits the work up into threads.  This calculation is done on arrays in the 100s of millions - so, it can take some time to complete.  CUDA is not a solution for this product, although I wish it was.  I do have access to boost and thus have some potential to use BLAS/uBLAS.

I'm thinking, however, that SIMD might yield much better results, but I'm not familiar enough with how to do this with complex numbers.  The code I have now is as follows (remember this is chunked up into threads which correspond to the number of cores on the target machine).  The target machine is also unknown.  So, a generic approach is probably best.

```
void cmult_scalar_inplace(fcomplex *values, const int start, const int end, const float *scalar)
{
    for (register int idx = start; idx < end; ++idx)
    {
        values[idx].real *= scalar[idx];
        values[idx].imag *= scalar[idx];
    }
}
```

fcomplex is defined as follows:

```
struct fcomplex
{
    float real;
    float imag;
};
```

I've tried manually unrolling the loop, as my finally loop count will always be a power of 2, but the compiler is already doing that for me (I've unrolled as far as 32). I've tried a const float reference to the scalar - in thinking I'd save one access - and that proved to be equal to the what the compiler was already doing.  I've tried STL and transform, which game close results, but still worse.  I've also tried casting to std::complex and allow it to use the overloaded operator for scalar * complex for the multiplication but this ultimately produced the same results.

So, anyone with any ideas?  Much appreciation is given for your time in considering this!  Target platform is Windows. I'm using Visual Studio 2008.  Product cannot contain GPL code as well!  Thanks so much.

Comment: If you use the Intel ICC compiler (which you can just plug in to Visual Studio) then it should be able to vectorize such a simple loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this fairly easily with SSE, e.g.

```
void cmult_scalar_inplace(fcomplex *values, const int start, const int end, const float *scalar)
{
    for (int idx = start; idx < end; idx += 2)
    {
        __m128 vc = _mm_load_ps((float *)&values[idx]);
        __m128 vk = _mm_set_ps(scalar[idx + 1], scalar[idx + 1], scalar[idx], scalar[idx]);
        vc = _mm_mul_ps(vc, vk);
        _mm_store_ps((float *)&values[idx], vc);
    }
}
```

Note that `values` and `scalar` need to be 16 byte aligned.

Or you could just use the Intel ICC compiler and let it do the hard work for you.

---

**UPDATE**

Here is an improved version which unrolls the loop by a factor of 2 and uses a single load instruction to get 4 scalar values which are then unpacked into two vectors:

```
void cmult_scalar_inplace(fcomplex *values, const int start, const int end, const float *scalar)
{
    for (int idx = start; idx < end; idx += 4)
    {
        __m128 vc0 = _mm_load_ps((float *)&values[idx]);
        __m128 vc1 = _mm_load_ps((float *)&values[idx + 2]);
        __m128 vk = _mm_load_ps(&scalar[idx]);
        __m128 vk0 = _mm_shuffle_ps(vk, vk, 0x50);
        __m128 vk1 = _mm_shuffle_ps(vk, vk, 0xfa);
        vc0 = _mm_mul_ps(vc0, vk0);
        vc1 = _mm_mul_ps(vc1, vk1);
        _mm_store_ps((float *)&values[idx], vc0);
        _mm_store_ps((float *)&values[idx + 2], vc1);
    }
}
```

Comment: They are 16 byte aligned.  I did that in an earlier optimization to all the data we were working on.  I'm off to try this.  I greatly appreciate your response!

Comment: Let me know how it goes - I think I can probably make the loading of vk more efficient so we may be able to get a little more performance. Having said that, there are so few operations relative to loads and store that you may already be memory bandwidth limited.

Comment: Ugh ... same average times, compiler is possibly already doing this?  I may have messed up something though getting it to compile for MSVC 2008.

Comment: word is that ICC costs too much for the moment.  So, I'm stuck on MSVC 2008.

Comment: Nevermind, on a different machines times are nearly twice as fast with this version.  I'd be interested to know your optimizations around vk!!!

Comment: @Keck: ICC is only around $500 - if performance is important then this is the most bang per buck you'll get so quickly, easily and reliably compared to having programmers write optimised code by hand.

Comment: @Keck: I think vk can probably be loaded more efficiently using a 64 bit MMX load followed by an SSE shuffle instruction, but I haven't had time to look at this in detail yet.

Comment: I couldn't agree with you more about that potential waste in money just by me working on it for even a few days.  I appreciate you looking into this.  We have many many many functions that take a long time that are in a similar vane.  So, this approach proving fruitful should allow me to implement other functions i.e. cross product, fft shifting, fft weighting, fft phasing, matrix multiplication, etc.  All of these things take a long time currently.  So, any improvement is pretty big given our data set sizes!

Comment: @Keck: if you want to make a case to TPTB then you can get a free 30 day evaluation of ICC from intel.com, re-compile your code with ICC and then benchmark it against the MSVC code. That should make a pretty compelling case. Good luck !

Comment: This definitely has given some some large speed increases on some machines in the building - a few of which are close to our largest customers specs.  So, I'm interested in any other optimizations you may have around the setting of vk.  I'm thinking, for now, that rewriting most of our similar functions in this regard may be the best I can do for the software at the moment.

A side note, for our smallest size, which is 4096*4096 or ~16million, this went from 48 milliseconds to 38 milliseconds. So, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Keck: great - glad it has helped - I'll take a look at the vk loading and see if I can improve on it, but you may be hitting memory bandwidth limits given the size of your data set.

Comment: another 4ms off the "worst case" time :)  Thanks so much!

Comment: Well, a quick change of heart.  I can now use MKL and TBB on this program ... Also, they said they will look at the ICC in the near future.  I didn't see that one coming ...

Comment: @Keck: OK - that should help with the other routines that you want to optimise. Certainly a lot easier/quicker than hand-coding SIMD.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet will be to use an optimised BLAS which will take advantage of whatever is available on your target platform.

Comment: I'm leaning towards trying it as well.  I'm unfamiliar with BLAS beyond the scope of MKL - in use on another product.  So, I'm hoping that the one in boost is more efficient than what I'm doing.  LGPL, BOOST license things are potentially possible, but we have strong traceability requirements on top of the "no money" issue.

Answer (score 1):

One problem I see is that in the function it's hard for the compiler to understand that the scalar pointer is not indeed pointing in the middle of the complex array (`scalar` could in theory be pointing to the complex or real part of a complex).
This actually forces the order of evaluation.

Another problem I see is that here the computation is so simple that other factors will influence the raw speed, therefore if you really care about performance the only solution is in my opinion to implement several variations and test them at runtime on the user machine to discover what is the fastest.

What I'd consider is using different unrolling sizes, and also playing with the alignment of `scalar` and `values` (the memory access pattern can have a big influence of caching effects).

For the problem of the unwanted serialization an option is to see what is the generated code for something like

```
float r0 = values[i].real, i0 = values[i].imag, s0 = scalar[i];
float r1 = values[i+1].real, i1 = values[i+1].imag, s1 = scalar[i+1];
float r2 = values[i+2].real, i2 = values[i+2].imag, s2 = scalar[i+2];
values[i].real = r0*s0; values[i].imag = i0*s0;
values[i+1].real = r1*s1; values[i+1].imag = i1*s1;
values[i+2].real = r2*s2; values[i+2].imag = i2*s2;
```

because here the optimizer has in theory a little bit more freedom.

Comment: this implementation also produced the same average times.  I do understand what you are saying though.  I appreciate your answer. I unrolled this to r4/i4/s4 when I attempted this.

Comment: I've tried many loop unrolling sizes.  Even as high as 32 and the same results are given both in isolation and in product.  I also caught a bug in this for the setting of s0, but as you can probably guess that had no affect on the time :P

Comment: @Keck: hehe... fixed. Originally there was `i+0` everywhere, I removed the wrong part from that (and btw writing this kind of stuff on iPad is a torture, apparently Apple hates programmers).

Comment: interestingly enough, on the best machine we have in the building, your implementation does offer a performance increase.  I've sent myself the generated assembly and I plan to look at all the implementations tonight in a learning effort :)  So, I greatly appreciate your help as well, because it's a new way to think about the problem if nothing else :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to Intel's Integrated Performance Primitives?
[Integrated Performance Primitives](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-ipp/)  They have a number of functions that handle cases like this with pretty decent performance. You might have some success with your particular problem, but I would not be surprised if your compiler already does a decent job of optimizing the code.

Comment: Another product has MKL/TBB/IPP in our company.  I program for that product as well, but this one does not have those licenses.  So, I'm foaming at the mouth to have that be the solution, but we can't use it for this one because of funding :/  So, it sucks to be very familiar with those products, but be unable to use them.
 
I fear also the compiler is already doing just about everything I can think to do with it for this approach.  I wish IPP was an option, but sadly it isn't.

Comment: @Keck: You don't need a special license for IPP *et al* any more. So long as you have a license for the ICC compiler then this covers distribution of binaries linked with IPP etc.

Comment: @Paul R So, it's of your opinion that if I, the developer, have a license through my company we can use it on another product?  I was told by some "people in charge," that was not the case.

Comment: @Keck: the licensing changed a couple of years ago when they started bundling IPP, MKL, etc in with the professional edition of the ICC compiler. So long as you have a valid license for ICC itself then any deliverables that you build will have no licensing issues even if they link to IPP or other Intel libraries. `IANAL` of course, so double check the Intel license, and maybe talk to your legal dept, but I'm 99.9% sure about this.

Comment: IPP does not have a complex/scalar multiply.